# How to mock a service in an integration test for a dynamically scaffolded Grails controller?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking

I'm trying to mock a service in an integration test for a dynamically scaffolded controller. I get an error indicating that the controller property for the service is not accessible from the test.

It seems that dynamically scaffolded controllers can't be tested with unit tests at all so I'm using integration tests. I want to mock the service to test error handling in my app.  Is this a bug in Grails 2.2.0 or am I just doing it wrong?

The result for `grails test-app` is:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: myService for class: MyController
```

Example:

I have modified the `src/templates/scaffolding/Controller.groovy`:

```
class ${className}Controller {
  MyService myService

  def action() {
    render myService.serviceMethod()
  }
}
```

Dynamically scaffolded `MyController.groovy`:

```
class MyController {
    static scaffold = MyDomainClass
}
```

Integration test `MyControllerTests.groovy`:

```
class MyControllerTests extends GroovyTestCase {
  def myController

  @Before
  void setUp() {
    myController = new MyController()
  }

  void testMock() {
    myController.myService = [ serviceMethod : { return "foo" } ] as MyService
    controller.action()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the setter method:

```
void testMock() {
    myController.setMyService([ serviceMethod : { return "foo" } ])
    controller.action()
}
```

If you execute: `println c.metaClass.methods*.name`, you will see that there are methods like getSetMyService() and getGetMyService(). I'm not sure of it, but probably Grails is not adding fields but instead getters for field get/set methods.

Comment: Thanks! controller.setXxxService() method did the trick! The Map as a parameter needs a typecast, though: `controller.setMyService([...] as MyService)`. Also, you need to reset the service to a real one for the next test. Grails seems to hold on to the mock after it is set. I'll show an example implementation in another answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The integration test should be implemented as shown below. If we mock the service in a test we must reset it ourselves. Grails does not do it for us which is mysterious because the controller is created in `setUp()`.

droggo's answer above reveals the correct way to inject the mock in the SUT. I'll also add an example of using a Groovy mock. It's bit more verbose though.

```
class MyControllerTests extends GroovyTestCase {
  def myController
  def myService

  @Before
  void setUp() {
    myController = new MyController()
  }

  @After
  void tearDown() {
    myController.setMyService(myService)
  }

  void testMapMock() {
    myController.setMyService([ serviceMethod : { return "foo" } ] as MyService)
    controller.action()
  }

  void testGroovyMock() {
    def myServiceMockContext = new StubFor(MyService)
    myServiceMockContext.demand.serviceMethod() { -> return "bar" }
    def myService = myServiceMockContext.proxyInstance()
    controller.setMyService(myService)
    controller.action()
  }
}
```